# iOS: how to add a search bar on navigation bar programmatically on a button press?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I know how to initialise the UIsearchcontroller by doing this:

```
let searchResultsController = UITableViewController(style: .Plain) as UITableViewController
searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self
searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
```

so,
I have a button on navigation bar and on press I want to display SearchBar using UISearchController and then dismiss the search bar on tapping again on the search button or empty space of screen.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, changing `active` property of search controller will move search bar to navigation bar

Comment: what I am looking for is how do I add the search bar to navigation bar when button is pressed and then remove it when pressing the button again or pressing on the empty screen.